# Javascript function that counts how many numbers are in the array (the array can contain other arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I write a function that, received an array `a` already given from the program that can contain numbers, boolean and even other arrays, counts how many numbers are present in `a`?

Here's my code that doesn't work (it gives everytime 0 whatever the array contains):

```
function test(a) {
    var sum = 0
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){
       if (typeof a[i]==Number)
           sum++                    
    }
    return sum 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should be comparing against a string, not the object: `typeof a[i] == "number"` (also, don't forget the `let`/`var` in your for loop before the `i` to avoid creating globals)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't still work. For example, with the array test([1,4, [2, 3, true], ["foo",0], 5, [123, [3.14, {a: 1}]]]) it should give 8 but it gives 3 (it only counts the numbers that aren't in other array)

Comment: Why should it give 8? Which numbers would it add to give you that sum?

Comment: Because it should count 1,4,2,3,0,5,123 and 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues:

- `typeof <operand>` returns a string and not an object, you should be checking against a string `typeof a[i] === "number"`.
- You should be using `var`/`let` before `i` in your `for` loop so that `i` doesn't become a global variable and instead remains scoped to your function (if you use `var`) or your `for` loop (if you use `let`). Having variables accidentally added to the global scope can easily lead to bugs for code that runs after you call your `test()` function.

As you want to count the frequency of numbers in both your array and nested arrays, you can use recursion. The idea is to call your `test()` function again inside of `test()` when you encounter an array:

```js
function test(a) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (typeof a[i] === "number")
      sum++
    else if(Array.isArray(a[i]))
      sum += test(a[i]); // sum the numbers within the `a[i]` array
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(test([1,4, [2, 3, true], ["foo",0], 5, [123, [3.14, {a: 1}]]])); // 8
```

The other option is to get JS to handle the recursion for you, which can be done with the help of the [`.flat()`](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat.) method. By using `.flat(Infinity)` you can first flatten your array (ie: remove the inner arrays of any level), and then loop over it:

```js
function test(a) {
  let sum = 0;
  let flat = a.flat(Infinity);
  for (let i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    if (typeof flat[i] === "number")
      sum++;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(test([1,4, [2, 3, true], ["foo",0], 5, [123, [3.14, {a: 1}]]])); // 8
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
const array = ["Hi", true, 10, "Car", 20, 50, 1500, false];
const flatedArray = array.flat(Infinity);
const count = flatedArray.filter(x => typeof x == 'number').length;
console.log(count) // 4
```

or change your code:

```
function test(a) {
    const flatedArray = a.flat(Infinity);
    let sum = 0
    for (i = 0; i < flatedArray.length; i++) {
        if (typeof a[i] == 'number') {
            sum++
        }
    }
    return sum
}

const array = ["Hi", true, 10, "Car", 20, 50, 1500, false];
console.log(test(array)) // 4
```

or change your function:

```
function test(a) {
    const flat = a.flat(Infinity);
    return a.filter(x => typeof x == 'number').length;
}

const array = ["Hi", true, 10, "Car", 20, 50, 1500, false];
console.log(test(array)) // 4
```

Comment: The array can have nested arrays with numbers inside of them, which should be counted also

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I made this change too ;) @NickParsons